# Sprite contact detection not working in swift

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I created a circle with 4 colors evenly divided, each color is a node.
Then there is another node that is a ball flying from top of the screen to the center of the scree, when the ball contacts the circle, score 1 point.
The issue I'm facing right now is that the contact detection is nor working, here is the code.

Also I want to know what's the better to set up setup separate physics bodies to each node in the FourColorSquare to detect collision with each color?

```
// move groups outside of class, so that other game scene can use it
```

`let ballGroup:UInt32 = 1
let nodeGroup:UInt32 = 2`

class FourColorCircle : SKShapeNode {

```
override init() {
    super.init()
    self.createCircle()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

func createCircle () {
    let center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
    // node1
    let node1bezierPath = UIBezierPath()
    node1bezierPath.addArcWithCenter(center, radius: 100, startAngle: 0.78, endAngle: 2.35, clockwise: true)
    node1bezierPath.addLineToPoint(center)

    let node1 = SKShapeNode(path: node1bezierPath.CGPath)
    node1.strokeColor = SKColor.redColor()
    node1.fillColor = SKColor.redColor()
    node1.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = nodeGroup
    node1.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = ballGroup
    node1.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = ballGroup
    self.addChild(node1)
    // node2
    let node2bezierPath = UIBezierPath()
    node2bezierPath.addArcWithCenter(center, radius: 100, startAngle: 2.35, endAngle: 3.92, clockwise: true)
    node2bezierPath.addLineToPoint(center)

    let node2 = SKShapeNode(path: node2bezierPath.CGPath)
    node2.strokeColor = SKColor.blueColor()
    node2.fillColor = SKColor.blueColor()
    node2.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = nodeGroup
    node2.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = ballGroup
    node2.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = ballGroup
    self.addChild(node2)
    // node3
    let node3bezierPath = UIBezierPath()
    node3bezierPath.addArcWithCenter(center, radius: 100, startAngle: 3.92, endAngle: 5.48, clockwise: true)
    node3bezierPath.addLineToPoint(center)

    let node3 = SKShapeNode(path: node3bezierPath.CGPath)
    node3.strokeColor = SKColor.greenColor()
    node3.fillColor = SKColor.greenColor()
    node3.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = nodeGroup
    node3.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = ballGroup
    node3.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = ballGroup
    self.addChild(node3)
    // node4
    let node4bezierPath = UIBezierPath()
    node4bezierPath.addArcWithCenter(center, radius: 100, startAngle: 5.48, endAngle: 0.78, clockwise: true)
    node4bezierPath.addLineToPoint(center)

    let node4 = SKShapeNode(path: node4bezierPath.CGPath)
    node4.strokeColor = SKColor.yellowColor()
    node4.fillColor = SKColor.yellowColor()
    node4.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = nodeGroup
    node4.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = ballGroup
    node4.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = ballGroup
    self.addChild(node4)

}

func rotate(angle : CGFloat, animated : Bool) {
    var rotateAction : SKAction!

    if animated {
        rotateAction = SKAction.rotateByAngle(angle, duration: 0.6)
    }
    else {
        rotateAction = SKAction.rotateByAngle(angle, duration: 0)
    }

    self.runAction(rotateAction)
}
```

}

```
class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

var ball = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 10)
var ballColor = ["red", "blue", "green", "yellow"]
let circle = FourColorCircle()

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self


    ball.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
    ball.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = ballGroup
    ball.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = nodeGroup
    ball.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = nodeGroup

    circle.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = nodeGroup
    circle.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = ballGroup
    circle.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = ballGroup


    backgroundColor = SKColor.whiteColor()
    circle.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
    self.addChild(circle)

    self.addChild(ball)
    ball.position = CGPointMake(150, 0)
    println("Initial Ball Pos:   \(ball.position)")

}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

    rotateCenterCircle()

    setBallPosition()

    setRandomColor()

    ballMove()

    // test ball position

    println("--------------")

    println("Ball Pos:   \(ball.position)")

    println("Circle pos: \(circle.position)")

    println("Midpoint:   \(CGPoint(x:CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y:CGRectGetMidY(self.frame) + self.frame.size.width))")

    println("--------------")

    // super.touchesBegan(touches as Set<NSObject> , withEvent:event)

}



override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */
}

func rotateCenterCircle() {

    circle.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
    circle.rotate(-3.14/2, animated: true)

}

func ballMove() {
    let ballMovement = SKAction.moveTo(CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame)), duration: 3)
    ball.runAction(ballMovement)
}

func setRandomColor() {
    ball.strokeColor = SKColor.whiteColor()
    ball.zPosition = 10


    let ballColorIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(ballColor.count)))
    switch(ballColorIndex) {
    case 0:
        ball.fillColor = SKColor.redColor()
    case 1:
        ball.fillColor = SKColor.blueColor()
    case 2:
        ball.fillColor = SKColor.greenColor()
    case 3:
        ball.fillColor = SKColor.yellowColor()
    default:
        println("Unexpected random index value ", ballColorIndex)
    }
}

func setBallPosition() {

    ball.position = CGPoint(x:CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y:CGRectGetMidY(self.frame) + (self.frame.size.width / 2))

    println("ball position = \(ball.position)")
}

func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

    if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == nodeGroup || contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == nodeGroup {

        println("contact")

    }

}
```

}

so when the two sprites contact each other, there is no log printed in the console.

Comment: Where do you init/create your nodes' physics bodies?

Comment: I didn't create one, how can I achieve it? I'm new to programming, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you can set properties for a node's physics body you first need to create one. There are volume based bodies such as a circle or rectangle and there are edge based physics bodies created from paths.

Seeing that you are currently working with balls, you would use a volume based body such as `init(circleOfRadius:)` or `init(circleOfRadius:center:)`. It's best if you read up on the [SKPhysicsBody](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsBody_Ref/) class reference before proceeding.